# Normalize json with related keys

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have JSON like this:

```
in_str='''{
  "prices": [
    [1, 10],
    [2, 20],
    [3, 30]    
  ],
  "total_volumes": [
    [1, 100],
    [2, 200],
    [3, 300]
  ]
}'''
```

And I am trying to produce pandas data frame with 3 columns (id, price, volume):

```
1 10 100
2 20 200
3 30 300
```

I've tried to use `pandas.read_json()`, but this gives me two columns and I don't know where to go next. `json_normalize()` gives me back only one row with two columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

in_str='''{
  "prices": [
    [1, 10],
    [2, 20],
    [3, 30]    
  ],
  "total_volumes": [
    [1, 10],
    [2, 20],
    [3, 30]
  ]
}'''

df = pd.read_json(in_str)
json_normalize(json.loads(in_str))
```

Comment: Can we assume that the ids in `prices` and `total_volumes` are in the same order?

Comment: @DeepSpace Yes, always the same order with both parts having always the same number of items.

Answer (score 1):

We could just read as usual, re-convert, and merge:

```
df = pd.read_json(in_str)
pd.merge(*[pd.DataFrame(np.array(df[col].to_list()), 
                        columns=['id', col]) for col in df],
         on='id')
```

Output:

```
   id  prices  total_volumes
0   1      10            100
1   2      20            200
2   3      30            300
```

Answer (score 1):

`pd.read_json` doesn't have a suitable `orient` parameter for this structure. It looks like it is easier to transform json and construct dataframe directly:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({key: dict(value) for key, value in json.loads(in_str).items()})

   prices  total_volumes
1      10            100
2      20            200
3      30            300
```

Answer (score 1):

You may pre-process json to appropriate dictionary and use it to construct the dataframe

```
import ast

d = ast.literal_eval(in_str)
d1 = {k: dict(v) for k, v in d.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(d1).rename_axis('id').reset_index()

Out[857]:
   id  prices  total_volumes
0   1      10            100
1   2      20            200
2   3      30            300
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to go download `pandas` if you're not already using it. Here's a solution that uses the builtin `json` parser to read the file, and native data structures to process the data into your desired shape (and maybe more useful shapes as well).

```py
import json

in_str='''{
  "prices": [
    [1, 10],
    [2, 20],
    [3, 30]    
  ],
  "total_volumes": [
    [1, 100],
    [2, 200],
    [3, 300]
  ]
}'''

in_json = json.loads(in_str)
# you can use json.load(filename) if you're using a file here.
print(in_json)
'''
>>> {'prices': [[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 30]], 'total_volumes': [[1, 100], [2, 200], [3, 300]]}
'''
# Here we're going to merge the two data sets to make them iterable in one go.
inventory = dict()
for item_id, price in in_json["prices"]:
  inventory[item_id] = {"price": price}

for item_id, volume in in_json["total_volumes"]:
  if isinstance(inventory.get(item_id), dict):
    inventory[item_id]["volume"] = volume
  else:
    inventory[item_id] = {"volume": volume}
print(inventory)
'''
>>> {1: {'price': 10, 'volume': 100}, 2: {'price': 20, 'volume': 200}, 3: {'price': 30, 'volume': 300}}
'''

# Now that the data is all in one dict, we can just iterate through it to get the rows in the shape that you want.
inventory_table = list()
for item_id, info in inventory.items():
  row = [item_id, info.get("price"), info.get("volume")]
  print(row)
  '''
  >>> [1, 10, 100]
  >>> [2, 20, 200]
  >>> [3, 30, 300]
  '''
  inventory_table.append(row)

# the final form
print(inventory_table)
'''
>>> [[1, 10, 100], [2, 20, 200], [3, 30, 300]]
'''
```

Now that we have that as a baseline, we can make some of the one-liners that people drool over in Python:

```py
import json

in_str='''{
  "prices": [
    [1, 10],
    [2, 20],
    [3, 30]    
  ],
  "total_volumes": [
    [1, 100],
    [2, 200],
    [3, 300]
  ]
}'''

in_json = json.loads(in_str)

inventory = {item_id: {"price": price} for item_id, price in in_json["prices"]}

for item_id, volume in in_json["total_volumes"]:
  if isinstance(inventory.get(item_id), dict):
    inventory[item_id]["volume"] = volume
  else:
    inventory[item_id] = {"volume": volume}

print(inventory)

inventory_table = [[item_id, info.get("price"), info.get("volume")] for item_id, info in inventory.items()]
print(inventory_table)
'''
>>> [[1, 10, 100], [2, 20, 200], [3, 30, 300]]
'''
```

Comment: I just re-read the question, and saw that the asker specifically requested Pandas. I'll leave this here anyway, and hope that it could be useful to someone else someday.